# Most secure implementation of User to User Msg in MongoDB app

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, messaging

This questions is more of a higher level question about MongoDB app structure.

I am currently building an App that can do User to User messaging using a MongoDB. Everything works great so far, but I am wondering if my design would lead to security issues.

I have a "UserDB" with a Collection "Users". In the collection, "Users" it stores documents of each Users data (Username, Password, ListOfMessages).

When one user sends a message to another user the structure is like this:

- User1 wants to send a message to User2
- User1 checks if User2 exists in the Collection
- if User2 exists, then add new Message to User2's list of Messages from User1
- Add the same message to User1 and mark as sent.

What I am concerned about is, should one user be able to access and modify another users data that way? I am concerned about potential hackers.

Any advice or resources would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not security issues that you'll run into, but rather scalability issues. For security, however, you should be encrypting your passwords and looking into security for password management.

But with this implementation you'll run into scalability issues. You don't want documents in your collections (your Users in this case) to be growing arbitrarily large (source: https://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/573fqr/question_mongodb_terrible_performance_for_a/).

Instead, you should create a new collection: Messages.

Each message will have documents like: {fromUser, toUser, message, date, ...}.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am allowing users to create only one account per device, so I am not too concerned about scalability of the users collection. You're right about encrypting passwords and I will be tackling that eventually. I also will be looking into TSL to prevent against packet sniffers.

My biggest concern is what if someone was to decompile my APK (android app) and write custom fuctions to say, delete all users etc. How can I protect against this? Do I need to make everything read only and have a separate admin level account?